# Homestead Laravel keeps running on previous version

Tags: homestead

I've following the steps in https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#updating-homestead, downloading the laravel/homestead (v10.1.1) but when i do `vagrant up`, i've the following message :

```
>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    homestead: Box Provider: virtualbox
    homestead: Box Version: ~> 9
==> homestead: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    homestead: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
==> homestead: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v9.6.1) for provider: virtualbox
```

How to *force* version 10.x ?

NB: I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: It appears that PHP version influences which homestead box gets added. PHP 7.2 and lower gets homstead 9.x

Answer (score 2):

Edit `Homestead.yaml` and add the following line `SpeakFriendAndEnter: true` underneath `provider: virtualbox` then run `vagrant up`

Comment: Sorry, i didn't notice your answer. But this line didn't change anything
`==> homestead: '11.0.0'. Run ``vagrant box update`` to update...`

Answer (score 0):

Try `vagrant up --provision` or destroy box and add a new one again.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
It didn't change anything, stucked with v9.6.1.
Worked with 8.x to 9.x, but not for 9.x to 10.x

Comment: Same here, it can't find the 10.1.1

Answer (score 0):

This had me confused for a while, but after some digging I found that the lower version that keeps getting installed is a package called `laravel/settler`. This is the actual vagrant box that is being installed but is registered as "laravel/homestead" on the official Vagrant listing. The `laravel/homestead` repo seems to be more of a development api wrapped around it. As of writing, the current version of `laravel/homestead` is `12.1` whereas the current version of `laravel/settler` is `11.0`. As far as I can tell `settler` is always one major version number behind `homestead`.

See:

https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead

https://github.com/laravel/settler

https://github.com/laravel/homestead

Comment: thanks, alas i don't have access anymore to this project.