# laravel with vagrant and virtualbox - version 10 installed but 11 when "vagrant up"

Tags: laravel, vagrant, version, virtualbox

After reinstall vagrant(2.2.14), virtualbox(6.1.16) and installing tue box with  the command found on the laravel website (ok for bash init.sh and the ssh-keygen), i have this :

```
$ vagrant box list
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 10.1.1)
```

When i try to launch this VM ("vagrant up" in the "~/Homestead" directory) i've got:

```
Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    homestead: Box Provider: virtualbox
    homestead: Box Version: >= 11.0
==> homestead: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    homestead: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
The box you're attempting to add has no available version that
matches the constraints you requested. Please double-check your
settings. Also verify that if you specified version constraints,
that the provider you wish to use is available for these constraints.

Box: laravel/homestead
Address: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
Constraints: >= 11.0
Available versions: 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5, 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.4, 0.2.5, 0.2.6, 0.2.7, 0.3.0, 0.3.3, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.4, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 4.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.0, 6.3.0, 6.4.0, 7.0.0, 7.1.0, 7.2.1, 8.0.0.pre.alpha1, 8.0.0.pre.alpha2, 8.0.0.pre.alpha3, 8.0.0.pre.alpha4, 8.0.0.pre.beta, 8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.1.0, 8.2.0, 8.2.1, 9.0.0, 9.0.1, 9.1.0, 9.1.1, 9.2.0, 9.3.0, 9.4.0, 9.5.0, 9.5.1, 9.6.0, 9.6.1, 9.7.2, 10.0.0, 10.1.0, 10.1.1
```

It is the second day i try to understand why "Constraints: >=11"... Some help?

Something else to notice maybe without importance. When i install the box it is redirecting to host: vagrantcloud-files-production.s3.amazonaws.com. It was not the same host when i installed it 1 year ago.

```
$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
This box can work with multiple providers! The providers that it
can work with are listed below. Please review the list and choose
the provider you will be working with.

1) hyperv
2) parallels
3) virtualbox
4) vmware_desktop

Enter your choice: 3
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v10.1.1) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/10.1.1/providers/virtualbox.box
Download redirected to host: vagrantcloud-files-production.s3.amazonaws.com
    box:
    box: Calculating and comparing box checksum...
==> box: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v10.1.1) for 'virtualbox'!
```

Answer (score 8):

\Homestead\scripts\homestead.rb

on line 21 i changed

```
unless settings.has_key?('SpeakFriendAndEnter')
    config.vm.box_version = settings['version'] ||= '>= 10.0'
end
```

Then up then ssh. It seems to be working fine.......... at the present time.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. I don't think it's mentioned anywhere in the documentation, so it is confusing, but the "box" Vagrant is referring to is a separate application from the homestead repo that you have cloned.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66633368/10221120